# Using a Set Builder Notation

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Please excuse my ignorance, I am doing a Mathematics for IT paper and have not done this type of maths for over 20 years.

The problem I have is this:

Let: $$T = \{x\, \lvert x \in \mathbb{R}, -10 \le x \le 5\}$$
Therefore I have figured out that $$T = \{-10, -9, -8. -7. -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$$

I have to use set builder notation to solve $T \cap {√2}$ .

The answer I keep coming back to is $\{\}$.  Could I please get assistance as to if I am on the right track?

Many thanks

Comment: It looks to me like 1.5 is also in T.

Comment: $T = [-10, 5]\subset \mathbb R$, and $\sqrt 2 \in \mathbb R$, greater than $-10$ and less than 5. So the intersection you speak of should be $\{\sqrt 2\}$

Comment: $T$ does not consist only of integers, but of the whole range of real numbers between $-10$ and $5$, eg $1,5$, $\frac{1}{3}$, $\pi$, and also $\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: You wrote $x\in $.  But $x \in $ what?  If tf is $x \in \mathbb Z $ then T is what you say it is and it only contains integers.  If it is $x\in \mathbb R $ then $T$ is the entire interval of $[-10,5] $ which is all real numbers, not just the intervals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $$T = \{x | x ∈ ℝ, -10 ≤ x ≤ 5\} = [-10,5]$$

is the set of all real numbers between $-10$ and $5$ inclusive.

Since $\sqrt 2$ is a member of $T$, we have $$T\cap \{\sqrt 2\} = \{\sqrt 2\} $$

Comment: Of course thank you, as real numbers are rational and irrational numbers.  Thank you once again :)

Comment: @Amanda Thank you for your attention and understanding.

Comment: So if I have another integer set W = {1...5} and the T set above is [-10,5,], would this intersection by written as T ∩ W = [1,5] ???

Comment: @Amanda, No. The set you have written for $T\cap W=[1,5]$ would include $1.2$ because of your use of the square braces $[ ]$. But $1.2$ cannot be in $T\cap W$ because $1.2$ is not in $W$.